# Using an adverb with a noun in Japanese

Tags: grammar, translation, particles, manga, english-to-japanese

> この先生…早くはないけどすごく仕事がていねいだな…

In the sentence above, this is my understanding so far:

**Vocabulary**

- この先生【せんせい】 that teacher…
- 早くない【はやくない】 fast, negative present form
- けど *conj.* however
- すごく *adv.* immensely
- 仕事【しごと】 *n.* work
- 『が』 *subject particle*
- ていねい *na-adj.* polite, courteous
- だ *non-formal copula*
- 『な』 *sentence ending particle*

My question is the following. How does すごく, an adverb, change the noun 仕事 (work)? I don't understand.

It is a sentence from the manga, 'Send my Regards to Black Jack', p. 13 episode 2 (for context):

https://www.sukima.me/bv/t/blackjackniyoroshiku/v/1/s/2/p/13

Answer (score 5, accepted):

すごく should be understood as modifying 仕事がていねい. The meaning will be more or less the same as

> 仕事がすごくていねいだ

Note that ていねい is used with "the other" meaning of "careful, thorough, meticulous, accurate, ..." here.

Comment: Are you saying すごく仕事がていねいだ is more colloquial than 仕事がすごくていねいだ? I don't think there is a difference in this regard (すごい is a casual word by itself, though)

Comment: @naruto Oh, my bad! To me it sounds like a more colloquial word order, but if to your native ears it doesn't sound this way I should remove this.